# How can I use copy to/from command in VNC on pi in my python code?

Tags: python, pi-zero, vnc

I am working with Raspberry Pi-0. Currently I am copying data from/to windows using VNC button at top.
I want to do it using python code i.e I want to access the commands used by VNC on Pi to copy data to/from windows in a python code running on Pi.
How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know if this is even possible, but why would you want to do something is such a roundabout way when there are established methods e.g. ftp, scp etc?

Answer (score 1):

One advantage of VNC is that you do not need to open any ports in the firewall to control the Pi.  A lot of companies are loathe for Pi boards to be installed on the LAN for this reason and often restrict access to the VNC cloud services because fo this (see NASA for why using a PI like this is a very bad idea).

With the free version of VNC the only way would be to emulate mouse and keyboard commands using something like Python and the python-uinput module [GITHUB link](https://github.com/tuomasjjrasanen/python-uinput)

Failing that, you could use the [SDK from RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/en/developer/) (chargeable product I think) and build on that.  Be default though this does NOT support file transfer natively so you would have to code both a version of VNC AND the file transfer into your own solution.